# Change the range of Earth Resistance Meter to measure lower resistance values

Tags: grounding, earth, meter

I have an analog Four Terminal Earth Resistance Meter with 100 ohms as the maximum range and 1 ohm is the resolution. The scale is linear. I need to measure low resistances below 1 ohm. How can I measure?

Comment: You could put it in parallel with a 1 ohm resistor, but then the scale would no longer be linear.

Comment: place the electrodes further apart